# How to change icons in cleditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cleditor

Hi I am using [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) in one of my projects.

I want to customize toolbar and change background of toolbar actions which is suitable to the theme of project. ( which i am not able to)

My findings are below

1. Height/width of action icon are hard coded to 24 value in jquery.cleditor.js.
2. Icons are taken from buttons.gif ( calculated from stripIndex of action in toolbar for background-position)

So i guess i will need to change both of these files ( button.gif/jquery.cleditor.js), which i believe is very tedious work.

Is there any easy way to set options to change icons in toolbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fork of cleditor where I changed the toolbar to use sprites so I could add
my own custom buttons easily might be able to use some of the work from that. I think
youd have to change the source code though.

https://github.com/billpull/cleditor
https://github.com/billpull/cleditor/commit/22dfe0b057360bdabab9ba184b8eef52f9de9ace